# Is there any significance to a red machine screw?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, screws

While cleaning the garage I found this red colored machine screw.

I know that green screws signify a ground connection but I've never heard specifics about red screws. Is this for any specific common use case?

[image: red screw]

Comment: Without context this question is too broad. It's going to generate a log list of possibilities and not solve a problem.

Comment: @isherwood can you give me some insight on how I might improve the question? For example had I posted a green colored machine screw like this people would likely identify it as an electrical grounding screw

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't _matter_ what the screw was intended for. It's laying around your garage. What problem are you trying to solve? If there _is_ a problem, ask that.

Comment: Another of the infinite possibilities is that it _looks nice_. Maybe it came off an automotive accessory or electronic device and needed to match.

Answer (score 16):

Commonly used for "shipping screws" to be removed before turning an appliance on.

Answer (score 11):

I've seen red machine screws on garage doors with torsion spring mechanisms. The red screws are the ones that you must not remove while the torsion spring is under tension, as removing them can release the mechanism and result in injury or death. If your garage door has a torsion spring, you might look for other red screws up high.

Comment: Wow - the fact that red screws sometimes mean "these must be removed" and sometimes mean "these must *not* be removed" is kind of surprising...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman  Yes, it's really a thing! See: https://ddmgaragedoors.com/blog/2018/04/14/why-red-paint-for-safety/

Comment: Wasn't doubting it, just surprised that the same indication can mean the exact opposite thing in some scenarios vs. others.

Comment: I don't find that surprising at all. Humans use colors for myriad purposes. Nothing is consistent across all industries, arts, and practices. The fact that it's a screw doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2):

In a mixed bag of screws (as one would get with a maintenance kit) some might get colored to be readily identifiable in that bag compared to the other similar looking ones.